# Collision when taking the last block of cbc as hash

Tags: encryption, hash, collision

I'm currently in the process of learning about encryption and i'm hoping to find more clarification on what I learned.

So for a specific problem encountered in class, where we discussed about using AES-128-CBC encryption and taking the last block as a hash. for example, to hash
the word "hello", it encrypts "hello" using AES-128-CBC and output the last block.

so I know it's not collision free, but is it possible to find the collision given key and iv? I've thought about vulnerabilities regarding pad or different length of messages, but at the end of the day I just don't think it's possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. [crypto.se] is much better suited for this type of question.

Comment: Concur, but I'll give a head start: this is almost CBC-MAC and vulnerable to adversarial attacks (_without_ the key) as described in Wikipedia; _with_ the key you can trivially do compensating changes to adjacent blocks because the underlying CBC encryption mode is not error-propagating. sometimes equivalently but more positively stated as re-synchronizing.